# Respond to volume buttons when phone is locked

Tags: android, volume, keyevent, locked, respond-to

I wrote an app which starts record audio in response to holding volume up button on phone or headphone, I'm doing it inside dispatchKeyEvent method and it's fine

Problem is, I want to do it when the phone is locked in my pocket, I want to just hold my headphone volume button and start recording, How can I do that in Android? How can you do anything in response to user actions when the phone is locked? For example, how can a music player respond to the user pressing play/pause button on headphone? I know that it is possible, but I don't know how...

Comment: Good question..